# Android tow activities shown in Recent Apps list

Tags: android, android-activity

I have MainActivity with Fragment that fragment contain ListView When the user click on a list item opens new Activity say PostActivity, When i press Recent button tow activities shown in Recent Apps list.
How i can solve this problem without finish() MainActivity?

The activities are NewMainActivity and SinglePostActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="net.ovtraining.wordpressapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="net.ovtraining.wordpressapp.SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="net.ovtraining.wordpressapp.NewMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="net.ovtraining.wordpressapp.LanguageSelectionActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="net.ovtraining.wordpressapp.SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName="net.ovtraining.wordpressapp.MainActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="net.ovtraining.wordpressapp.ui.SinglePostActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:parentActivityName="net.ovtraining.wordpressapp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data 
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="net.ovtraining.wordpressapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your manifest where you define the activity `android:excludeFromRecents="true"`

For example

```
<activity 
android:name=".MyActivity"
android:excludeFromRecents="true">
```

Comment: But I want only last opend activity appear in Recent Apps list. How can I do this? Something like Facebook app when you press status button then press back button.

Comment: You cannot stop other applications from showing in the recents list

Comment: Yeah I know that. In my app I want only last opend activity appear in the Recent Apps list.